# Javascript array check value and assign into the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

So, I have a PHP function that will read a csv file and then pass it to the angularJS.

Inside the csv file, there are 4 types of data

```
[0] => Number,
[1] => Code,
[2] => Description,
[3] => Qty
```

However, there is also "Area" data. The "Area" will be on "number" [2]

```
[0] => "",
[1] => "",
[2] => Area,
[3] => ""
```

This is the illustration

```
//Part 1
"","","Area 1",""
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
//Part 2
"","","Area 2",""
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
"No","Code","Description","QTY"
//And so on
```

What I want to achieve is, how can I get the area and then push it into my array by checking if [0] is empty and [2] is not null, then it is the area for the rest of array object, and once it detects same condition as before, it will assign new area for another part.

This is my array, called vm.products

```
for (var index = 0; index < resp.data.csv.length; index++) {
   vm.products.push({
      code: resp.data.csv[index][1],
      qty: resp.data.csv[index][3], 
      //area: resp.data.csv[index].area,
      description: resp.data.csv[index][2]
   });
}
```

Thank you for any help given :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to check whether the current entry contains the Area. If so, store it until the next Area comes by. When that happens, just replace the old Area with the new one.

While pushing the products to the array, just use the Area variable as it will always contain the correct Area.

```
var area = “”;
for (var index = 0; index < resp.data.csv.length; index++) {
    var current = resp.data.csv[index];
    if (current[2] != “” && (!current[0] || current[0] == "") {
        area = current[2];
    } else {
        vm.products.push({
            code: current[1],
            qty: current[3], 
            area: area,
            description: current[2]
        });
    }
}
```

This solution will loop only once over your array instead of multiple times when using a map first in the answer below.

Comment: Sir, the code almost works perfectly, but how can I not push into the array while there is no product code? because by the code you have written, it will add null product code into the array.. :)

Comment: No problem, updated my code (you need to move the code which pushes the products into the array in the else block)

Comment: sir the code now works perfectly! thank you so much for helping a junior programmer like me! really appreciate it and have a nice day Sir! Still need to learn more :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just map and filter the data:

```
var area;
var res = arr.map(function (d) {
    if (d[0] == "" && d[2] != null) {
        area = d[2];
        return null;
    }

    return {
        code: d[1],
        qty: d[3],
        area: area,
        description: d[2]
    }

}).filter(function (f) {
    return f;
});

console.log(res);
```

Output for your sample data:

```
[ { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 1',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 1',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 1',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 1',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 1',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 2',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 2',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 2',
    description: 'Description' },
  { code: 'Code',
    qty: 'QTY',
    area: 'Area 2',
    description: 'Description' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply sir mmm :). Really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this;

```js
var csvStr = '"","","Area 1",""\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"","","Area 2",""\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"\n"No","Code","Description","QTY"',
csvDataArr = csvStr.replace(/"/g,'').split("\n").map(s => s.split(",")),
      area,
csvDataObj = csvDataArr.reduce((p,c) => {c[0] === "" &&
                                         c[1] === "" &&
                                         c[3] === ""  ? p[area = c[2]] = []
                                                      : p[area].push(c);
                                         return p;
                                        },{});
console.log(csvDataObj);
```